# Windows Server error: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: asp.net, server, iis-7.5, nopcommerce

We have the following setup: Windows Web Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 on which we are running an instance of Nopcommerce v3.8. We have a plugin that is used to send products listed in our online store to eBay. 
If a product has less images(1-2) everything is fine, but if the images are more(4-8) we get the "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." error message.
We dont't get this issue when we test from a local installation of nopcommerce, so obviously this is a server configuration issue.
I tried changing config settings on server and in web.config as suggested in some posts([Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)) but none seemed to do the job.
It will be great if someone can point me to a possible solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you've configured store URL properly, check warnings!